# Toggle Switch update database

Tags: javascript, php, html

I need some help with a problem I'm having.

I have a PHP query which fetches a list of users from a table then I generate checkboxes on whether or not the user as able to view a page (this just reads a value from a column in a table), so that on the HTML page when it first loads it displays a list of check boxes showing which users have access and which users do not. At this particular time this is working fine, a tick is shown where I would expect to be if the user is set to 'Block', the issue I am having is allowing the 'Admin' user to control this and updating the database accordingly.

Here is my code for generating the checkboxes

```
<?php
$conection = new PDO('<<connection details>>');
$users = $connection->query("<<SELECT QUERY>>");

while ($row = $users->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    if ($row['BlockUser'] == '1') {
        $user_visi_list.= "<div class=\"checkbox checkbox-danger\">
                           <input id=".$row['UserID']." value=".$row['UserID']." name=\"agreement[]\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"styled\" checked=\"\">
                           <label for=".$row['UserID'].">".$row['UserName']."</label>
                           </div>";
    }
    else {
        $user_visi_list.= "<div class=\"checkbox checkbox-danger\">
                           <input id=".$row['UserID']." value=".$row['UserID']." name=\"agreement[]\" type=\"checkbox\" class=\"styled\">
                           <label for=".$row['UserID'].">".$row['UserName']."</label>
                           </div>";
    }
  }
  echo $user_visi_list;
?>
```

So from this code above, it checks the database and generates either a 'Ticked' checkbox or 'Unticked' checkbox, depending on the value in the column of the database table, as I said, this part works as expected.

The trouble I am having is, how can I now let the 'Admin' user update the checkbox status and have that update to the database?

I've looked at several solutions but they mostly involve javascript and knowing the checkbox name or ID, which in my case are dynamically created and I've no way of hard coding that information.

I have managed so far to use PHP to return an array of the 'Ticked/Checked' values, but that doesn't really help me, as I need to know which boxes are 'Unticked/Unchecked', so that I can update the database with that value too.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have all information you need, just add a click event and then you check the attributes like id and value

Comment: Hi John, sorry, I'm sort of new to this but how would I go about doing that if I don't know the ID or name of the checkbox?

Comment: you do know the name its `agreement[]` further you could add the same class to all checkboxes in your php loop

Comment: just add common class to your checkbox and use that class in jQuery to get checkbox click event inside function use this object to get that element other attribute

Comment: I'm really sorry guys but could you expand on this, what would the jQuery look like if I were to use a common class within the PHP loop?